# React Native RefreshControl component flicker / blink

Tags: react-native, scrollview

So I'm using a RefreshControl inside a scrollview. the onRefresh prop is passed to a child with the scroll view and is something like

```
const onRefresh = () => {
setRefreshing(true);
//do some stuff (that also changes state)
setRefreshing(false);
}
```

What happens is since the stuff I execute in the middle updates the state and triggers the re rendering of the screen, the refresh indicator re-renders, it goes from big to small (dissapears) to big very fast, not sure how to explain it, it looks like it blinks
I just want the spinner to stay the same until refreshing is false

Did anyone had this problem?
thanks

Comment: probably `do some stuff` part is async and you are not waiting it to be completed before `setRefreshing(false);`

Comment: like Uğur Eren says you are probably calling an API and that has to be async. so move the `setRefreshing(false)` to the place after the Api invocation is actually completed. The best way would be to move `setRefreshing(true);` and `setRefreshing(false);` to an function calling the API block and also adding try catch block to the APi call.